# Change multiple Autosys jobs Status in one go

Tags: autosys

Is it possible to change status of multiple Autosys jobs to ON_ICE.
**I tried by using,**

```
sendevent -e CHANGE_STATUS -s ON_ICE –j jobname1
sendevent -e CHANGE_STATUS -s ON_ICE –j jobname2
sendevent -e CHANGE_STATUS -s ON_ICE –j jobname3
sendevent -e CHANGE_STATUS -s ON_ICE –j jobname4
```

**but getting following error,**

> "Attributes cannot be accepted without a valid JIL subcommand."

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use a sendevent with the flag -F and specify a file name which has all the jobs that you want to perform and sendevent on.

```
sendevent-F jobs_on_ice
```

Dave